# Looking for working example of Oracle DBMS_WM.Export_Schemas function

Tags: oracle, plsql, datapump

I'm working with Oracle 19.6 and I'm trying to export versioned data using Workspace Manager.
The official documentation (https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/adwsm/DBMS_WM-reference.html#GUID-9485C70D-9CF9-4649-8785-06C7D6CF32D6) shows an example but I was not able to make it work.

Using "sys" user, the code returns "ORA-20283: invalid job_name parameter specified" at line "dbms_wm.export_schemas(job_name) ;"

With a dedicated user (the documentation says "The Data Pump job should not be created while using SYSDBA privileges") I get another error :

```
31626. 00000 -  "job does not exist"
*Cause:    An invalid reference to a job which is no longer executing,
           is not executing on the instance where the operation was
           attempted, or that does not have a valid Master Table.
           Refer to any following error messages for clarification.
*Action:   Start a new job, or attach to an existing job that has a
           valid Master Table.
```

Another thing that bother me is that the sample code does not call "DBMS_DATAPUMP.START_JOB" as in regular datapump job.

SR has been open to Oracle support for a long time so any help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Edit :
As per the documentation, versioned data can be exported and imported with data pump and FULL=Y option. Doing so (and disabling all WMSYS triggers beforehand), returns tons of ORA-39111 and ORA-31684 as I didn't drop the objects in the target database, but strangely, "SPATIAL_CSW_ADMIN_USR" user is not present in the dump which leads to cascade of errors.

At the end of the day, import is "successfull" with 5685 errors but the content of ALL_WORKSPACES table shows only the default entry (nammed LIVE) when 12 are present in the source database.

Comment: Taking a step back, is there a DBA out there that successfully export and import Oracle workspace, by using **Export_schemas** function or other methods ?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the steps I followed to successfully export versionned tables using dbms_wm.export_schemas :

Create a dedicated user to run the export :

```
create user sigea_exp identified by sigea_exp;
grant create session, create table, create procedure, exp_full_database, imp_full_database, DATAPUMP_EXP_FULL_DATABASE to sigea_exp;
GRANT UNLIMITED TABLESPACE TO sigea_exp;
grant read, write on directory EXPORT_AUTOMATIQUE to sigea_exp;
begin
    DBMS_WM.GRANTSYSTEMPRIV('ACCESS_ANY_WORKSPACE','sigea_exp', 'NO',TRUE);
end;
```

Check that WMSYS schema does not contain errors (connected as "sys" no row returned by the following statement) :

```
select * from ALL_OBJECTS where status = 'INVALID' and OWNER = 'WMSYS';
```

Run the following script, chosing carefully the name of the DIRECTORY (here 'EXPORT_AUTOMATIQUE'):

```
DECLARE
  job_name varchar2(128) := 'EXPORT_EAU_2';
  dpj number ;
BEGIN
  dpj := dbms_datapump.open('EXPORT', 'SCHEMA', null, job_name, 'COMPATIBLE');
  dbms_datapump.add_file(dpj, 'eau_schema.dmp', 'EXPORT_AUTOMATIQUE');
  dbms_datapump.add_file(dpj, 'eau_schema.log', 'EXPORT_AUTOMATIQUE', filetype=>dbms_datapump.KU$_FILE_TYPE_LOG_FILE);
  dbms_wm.export_schemas(job_name, 'WMSYS_N', FALSE);
  DBMS_DATAPUMP.START_JOB(dpj);
END;
/
```